# Azure cosmos DB 3.6 Mongo doesn't support Compound index that has embedded field

Tags: mongodb, indexing, field, azure-cosmosdb

When I run the following command in Cosmos DB 3.6,

`db.collectionName.ensureIndex({"Contract.ContractNumber":1, "PBPNumber":1})`

`Contract.ContractNumber` is the sub-document path.

I got his error

```
{
   "ok" : 0,
   "errmsg" : "Compound index does not currently support nested documents or arrays.",
   "code" : 115,
   "codeName" : "CommandNotSupported"
}
```

The same command succeeds in out of box Mongo.

Is there anyway to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the `CommandNotSupported` error message,the feature is not supported exactly currently.

Per my knowledge, CosmosDB just supports a subset of the MongoDB API. CosmosDB has some different behaviours and results. But the onus is on CosmosDB to improve their emulation of MongoDB.

Surely, you could add [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db) here to submit your requirements.Or you could consider using [MongoDB Atlas](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/microsoft-azure/) on Azure if you'd like full MongoDB feature support.

Comment: I've created a new request, as I came across the same issue: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/40015003-unique-index-in-nested-documents-or-arrays

Comment: @PeterY, please find this link to the current CosmosDB Mongo API indexing options. I hope you found a solution to  your issue. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-indexing

Answer (score 0):

As of May 2022, indexing is available for nested compound indices, as long as none of the properties in the dot-notation path (excluding the last element) is an array.

However, as explained [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/ad9a64e6-0e25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0858).

> Because of the difficulty of ensuring that all data within a collection cannot include an array on the property being set, we can only enable this via support ticket

P.S. We found it is possible to ask Azure support to enable the feature on a CosmosDB instance, not just on individual collections.

Comment: It seems that there's another requirement: no 'unique' flag on any of the indexed fields.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding @leopold.talirz answer:

It seems that it actually is possible to enable this feature all by yourself. Please see [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/indexing#limitations-1) for overall reference, and then there's [a link to another one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/how-to-configure-capabilities) which explains step-by-step how to do it.

EDIT: most recent news seem to be here:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/101394#issuecomment-1318041341

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/19192#issuecomment-1341332461

It seems it WILL be available to users "shortly", but so far, it's only available to MSFT, and the docs were updated too soon.

what a mess